# Filter program in C does not work on more complex images

Tags: c

I need to write a program which makes a grayscale filter. It works only partially and I am having the following error messages:

```
:) grayscale correctly filters single pixel with whole number average
:( grayscale correctly filters single pixel without whole number average
    expected "28 28 28\n", not "27 27 27\n"
:) grayscale leaves alone pixels that are already gray
:) grayscale correctly filters simple 3x3 image
:( grayscale correctly filters more complex 3x3 image
    expected "20 20 20\n50 5...", not "20 20 20\n50 5..."
:( grayscale correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "20 20 20\n50 5...", not "20 20 20\n50 5..."
```

The code is below:

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) //Loop thought each row of 2D array
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)//Loop through each pixel of each row
        {

            int red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            int blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            int green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            int avr = round((red + blue + green) / 3);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtRed = avr;

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: where do you get these errors?

Comment: If the checker is expecting 28 and you get 27 it would the seem your division and rounding aren't correct. What do you get it you divide by 3.0? There's probably a note somewhere in the assignment that warns against integer division.

Comment: @LoadingThe last two messages are unclear.  Please explain how those are errors.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's output from the `check50` program which is part of the CS50 class.

Comment: @RetiredNinja OP posted "expected "20 20 20\n50 5...", not "20 20 20\n50 5...".  It could also be a transcription error on OP's part as the reported expected and actual are the same.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The real issue in those cases is hidden behind the `...`. There used to be a way to get the full message but it's been a few years so the program may have changed. *shrug*

Comment: Thank you all for taking of your time and helping me to solve the problem. I divided by a double- 3.0 and all works fine. I was getting the errors from a system created by the online course I am doing that checks the result before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round()` ineffective as the quotient of two `int`s is as `int`.  Rounding that
`int` has no effect.

```
//                 ........int........  / int
// int avr = round((red + blue + green) / 3);

// Divide by a `double`
int avr = round((red + blue + green) / 3.0);
// or
int avr = lround((red + blue + green) / 3.0);

// or even better, round with integer math.
int avr = ((red + blue + green)*2 + 3)/6;
```

Other problems may exist, but this explains "expected "28 28 28\n", not "27 27 27\n".